# Store the values for each key as an array in a dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop

I would like to normalize all values in the dictionary `data` and store them again in another dictionary with the same keys and for each key the values should be store in 1D array so I did the following:

```
>>> data = {1: [0.6065306597126334], 2: [0.6065306597126334, 0.6065306597126334, 0.1353352832366127], 3: [0.6065306597126334, 0.6065306597126334, 0.1353352832366127], 4: [0.6065306597126334, 0.6065306597126334]}

>>> norm = {k: [v / sum(vals) for v in vals] for k, vals in data.items()} 

>>> norm
{1: [1], 2: [0.4498162176582741, 0.4498162176582741, 0.10036756468345168], 3: [0.4498162176582741, 0.4498162176582741, 0.10036756468345168], 4: [0.5, 0.5]}
```

Now suppose the dictionary `data` contains only a zero value for one of it's keys like the value of the first key `1`:

```
>>> data = {1: [0.0], 2: [0.6065306597126334, 0.6065306597126334, 0.1353352832366127], 3: [0.6065306597126334, 0.6065306597126334, 0.1353352832366127], 4: [0.6065306597126334, 0.6065306597126334]}
```

then normalizing the values of this dictionary will result by `[nan]` values because of the division by zero

```
>>> norm = {k: [v / sum(vals) for v in vals] for k, vals in data.items()}

__main__:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
>>> norm
{1: [nan], 2: [0.4498162176582741, 0.4498162176582741, 0.10036756468345168], 3: [0.4498162176582741, 0.4498162176582741, 0.10036756468345168], 4: [0.5, 0.5]}
```

So I inserted an `if statement` to overcome this issue but I can't store the values for each key as a ID array

the code

```
>>> norm = {}
>>> for k, vals in data.items():
...     values = []
...     if sum(vals) == 0:
...        values.append(list(vals))
...     else:
...          for v in vals:
...              values.append(list([v/sum(vals)]))
...     norm[k]=values
... 
>>> norm
{1: [[1.0]], 2: [[0.4498162176582741], [0.4498162176582741], [0.10036756468345168]], 3: [[0.4498162176582741], [0.4498162176582741], [0.10036756468345168]], 4: [[0.5], [0.5]]}
```

I would like to get the `norm` dictionary as

```
norm = {1: [1.0], 2: [0.4498162176582741, 0.4498162176582741, 0.10036756468345168], 3: [0.4498162176582741, 0.4498162176582741, 0.10036756468345168], 4: [0.5, 0.5]}
```

Also, For the dictionary `data`, while it contains a zero value for one if it's keys, is there a better solution to normalize it because I think that my solution is not efficient!

P.S: I tried at the end of the for loop `norm[k]= np.array(values)` instead of   `norm[k]=values` but the result was not as required.

Comment: Change both your `append` to `extend`. Also, no need to create a `list` from what is being extended, it already is a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in an answer, `extend` can be used to solve your problem. If you do want to use `append`, you could take the first element of your lists.

```
norm = {}
for k, vals in data.items():
    values = []
    if sum(vals) == 0:
        values.append(vals[0])
    else:
        for v in vals:
            values.append([v / sum(vals)][0])
    norm[k] = values
```

See [**difference between append vs extend list methods in python**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/difference-between-append-vs-extend-list-methods-in-python) for an example of append vs extend

As for the optimization. Completely removing the for loops won't be possible but you can shortify your solution, while still maintaining readability:

```
norm = {}
for k, vals in data.items():
    if sum(vals) == 0:
        norm[k] = vals
    else:
        norm[k] = [x / sum(vals) for x in vals]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Is there a more efficient way to get this dictionary isntead of all of these loops?

Comment: @Noah16 I have updated my answer. Please upvote and accept my answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

`append` as mentioned above adds an element to a list, and this element can be a list, that's why you currently have a list within a list. Ideally, you should be using `extend` which concatenates the first list with another list.

Answer (score 0):

Your dict/list comprehension fails when `sum(vals) == 0`:

```
>>> data = {1: [0.0], 2: [0.6065306597126334, 0.6065306597126334, 0.1353352832366127], 3: [0.6065306597126334, 0.6065306597126334, 0.1353352832366127], 4: [0.6065306597126334, 0.6065306597126334]}
>>> {k: [v / sum(vals) for v in vals] for k, vals in data.items()}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <dictcomp>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <listcomp>
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

You can introduce a ternary expression to handle the case:

```
>>> {k: [v / sum(vals) if sum(vals)!=0 else 1.0 for v in vals] for k, vals in data.items()}
{1: [1.0], 2: [0.4498162176582741, 0.4498162176582741, 0.10036756468345168], 3: [0.4498162176582741, 0.4498162176582741, 0.10036756468345168], 4: [0.5, 0.5]}
```

If you want to avoid to evalaute `sum(vals)` multiple times:

```
>>> {k: [v / s if s!=0 else 1.0 for v in vals] for k,vals,s in ((k, vals, sum(vals)) for k, vals in data.items())}
{1: [1.0], 2: [0.4498162176582741, 0.4498162176582741, 0.10036756468345168], 3: [0.4498162176582741, 0.4498162176582741, 0.10036756468345168], 4: [0.5, 0.5]}
```

`((k, vals, sum(vals)) for k, vals in data.items())` is a generator that returns `k`, `vals` and `sum(vals)` for every item.

Answer (score 0):

This should work as well:

```
norm = {k: [v / sum(vals) for v in vals] if sum(vals)!=0 else [1] for k, vals in data.items() }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).